# Finding relations among supremum of sets of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of real numbers and write $C = A \cap B$. Find a relation among sup $A$, sup $B$, and sup $C$.

I am not sure how to write the proof for this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sup A = M$ and $\sup B = N$.

Then $C(=A\cap B) \subset A$ and $C\subset B$.

Therefore $M,N$ are upper bounds of $C$.

Therefore $\sup C \le M$ and
$\sup C \le N$.

So $\sup C\le \min\{M,N\}$.

Comment: If you need the proof for $A\subset B\implies supA \le supB$, I'll give one.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**

If $X\subseteq Y$, then $\sup X \leq \sup Y$.

**Proof**

Suppose otherwise, that is to say, $\sup X > \sup Y$.

Then there exists at least an $x\in X$ such that $\sup Y < x \leq \sup X$. On the other hand, $x\not\in Y$.

Indeed, if it was the case, we would have $x\leq\sup Y$, which leads to a contradiction.

Therefore $\sup X\leq \sup Y$, and we are done.

**Solution**

Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$, one has that
\begin{align*}
\sup(C) = \sup(A\cap B) \leq\min\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.